# Alchemic fire/bomb vs. Swarm of Fine creatures

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, swarm

There is another discussion in our group and since my Google Foo and Rules Lawyering skill is not very high, I decided to bring this up.

According to [swarm traits](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html#swarm-subtype)

> A swarm composed of Fine or Diminutive creatures is immune to all weapon damage.    `Statement A`

After that it stated that:

> A swarm is immune to any spell or effect that targets a specific number of creatures `...skipped...`    `Statement B`

And main thing about alchemist fire/bomb is that:

> A swarm takes half again as much damage (+50%) from spells or effects that affect an area, such as splash weapons and many evocation spells.    `Statement C`

From description of [splash weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#throw-splash-weapon):

> A splash weapon is a ranged weapon that breaks on impact, `...skipped...`    `Statement D`

means splash weapon is a **weapon**, not spell or effect. More over is says:

> A hit deals direct hit damage to the target, and splash damage to all creatures within 5 feet of the target.    `Statement E`

I rule that statement C (defined later than A or B), overrides both statement A and statement B, allowing any splash weapon to be an exception from weapons that can attack swarm and making it deal extra half again as much damage (+50%), despite not being spell or effect (confirmed by statements D and E).

*Do you agree on my ruling or you think it should be otherwise around?*

If there is some official statement about alchemical fire vs swarm than, could you please link it up. I am already aware about [damaging swarms with flaming/cold/electricity weapon](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2lzpi?Question-about-swarms#34) and [damaging swarms with rays](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5lbjm?Get-Lost#8).

Answer (score 3):

My understanding:

> A hit deals direct hit damage to the target, and splash damage to all creatures within 5 feet of the target.

There’s the damage from a direct hit by the weapon (the “weapon damage”), and then there is the “splash damage”). You cannot score a direct hit on a swarm (or, you can, but it doesn’t matter), but the splash damage is empowered.

Note that since the splash damage for such weapons is often **1**, the empowerment does nothing. Houseruling to allow the direct hit would allow non-spellcasters to have a chance of doing something meaningful against swarms, so I would call that a good change. Note, however, that alchemical weapons are often quite weak and fairly expensive; they are still not a *good* solution for non-spellcasters. Note that the issue of mundane responses to swarms has come up before: the conclusion was that [as a player, there are pretty much no good options](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18888/4563), and [even as a DM, there’s not much you can do to help a mostly-mundane party succeed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22888/4563). Swarms are an excellent, early example of how badly Pathfinder divides the magical (read: capable) and mundane (read: incapable) classes.